# How can I set 100% height on a div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need the divs using class .gray and .yellow blocks to be 100% of the height of the content, that is 100% possible height between the header and the footer.

Please tell me how to do it?

[Example](http://codepen.io/untca/pen/YGXvNX):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
}

#page-content {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -80px;
}

#page-buffer {
  height: 80px;
}

footer {
  height: 80px;
  background: #f00;
}

.yellow {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.gray {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100%;
  
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.h100{
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-content">
  <header class="blue">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 ">
          some header
         
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container  h100">
    <div class="row  h100">
      <div class="col-sm-8 gray same">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 yellow same">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi consectetur, recusandae sapiente! Beatae facilis cupiditate, a iure officiis alias quibusdam.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="page-buffer"></div>
</div>

<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        some footer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: remove container class

Comment: You need to include all relevant code to replicate the issue directly in the question. Not just a URL for codepen

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have a fixed header and a fixed footer height.

In this case I do something like this in css

height: calc(100% - /FotterHeight/px - /headerHeight/px);

Comment: I do not know the height of the header , because the site is adaptive and header inside the carousel images

Comment: than you could read the header height with java script and then set the content height with this formula
<script> var rect = document.getElementById("header").getBoundingClientRect();
var rect_bottom = document.getElementById("footer").getBoundingClientRect();
var rect_body = document.getElementById("body").getBoundingClientRect();
document.getElementById("content").style.height =  rect_body.height -rect.height - rect_bottom.height;
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Give your header a height and calculate footer and header from overall height

```
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: calc(100vh - 130px);
}

.gray {
  background-color: gray;
  height: calc(100vh - 130px);
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks? but
I do not know the height of the header , because the site is adaptive and header inside the carousel images

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do with javascript. Just add below the body tag. But you must give header a height and minus that from total height; here below headerHeight is not defined;

```
<script>
var headerHeight = document.getElementById("headerHt"),
    totalHeight = document.getElementById("page-content"),
    classGray = document.querySelector(".gray"),
    classYellow = document.querySelector(".yellow");

classGray.style.height = classYellow.style.height = totalHeight.clientHeight - headerHeight.style.height + "px";

</script>
```